# How do I mark a channel as nsfw with discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a feature in my discord bot that will automatically set up a server for you, but I haven't found a way to mark a created channel as nsfw. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextChannel` has a method called [`.setNSFW()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=setNSFW). Use that to set the channel to nsfw. If you want to set that during the channel creation, then the `GuildChannelManager#create()` method has an option [type for nsfw](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create). Set that parameter to true to make it a nsfw channel.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need if you create channel from beginning

```
message.guild.channels.create('Channel name',{
  nsfw: true,
})
```